# Represent a small bilingual lexicon as a Javascript object

Tags: javascript

list of words that I want to convert to Swedish if they
happen to be present

```
 var translate = {
     "merry":"god", 
     "christmas":"jul", 
     "and":"och", 
     "happy":"gott", 
     "new":"nytt", 
     "year":"år"     
};

// prompt for the text to be translated
var qu = prompt("what would you like to translate?");

// switching it into an array
var result = qu.split(" ");

// empty string to store my answer
var realResult = "";

// for loop to browse through the items in my array
for(i = 0 ; i < result.length ; i++){

/* place where im stuck, whatever I come up doesnt result in proper answer.
I tried to use for(asd in translate) loop to compare every element
but there is something im missing
*/
// if the item in the array is equal to the item in object replace
// that item 
    if( result[i] === translate[????] ){
        realResult += translate.i + " ";

// else put the item from array into the string        
    } else {
        realResult += result[i] + " ";
    }
}
// print out the result
console.log(realResult);
```

I might be totally wrong here and the answer might lie somewhere else. thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just substitute this part:

```
 if( result[i] === translate[????] ){
    realResult += translate.i + " ";

// else put the item from array into the string        
} else {
    realResult += result[i] + " ";
}
```

With this line:

```
realResult += ( translate[result[i]] || result[i] ) + " ";
```

Comment: thank you very much, as usual, the answer was rather short, when I was even trying to go through double for loops. much appreciated

Comment: @Sniffer Please note that begging for upvotes/reputation is generally frowned upon by the community. Though not addressing accepts, here is an [reference Meta Post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63439/begging-for-votes/)

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 Thank you. I am well aware of that. The problem is that sometimes *(this is one of them)* the OP might be new and have just joined the site so he is not full aware of forum rules, what down-voting or up-voting is. I should have gave him a link to the forum rules, that's what I have really missed. Thank you.

Comment: @Sniffer :) You're welcome. Yes, providing a link to e.g. the [about] page via `[about]`  would probably the better choice, than filling the comment section with noise.

Comment: indeed, that was my first post so I didnt know the drill. Im happy that my simple question has been resolved without any drama :D